# is this unit test or integration test? I have doubts about this

Tags: unit-testing

Imagine that I have a method that sum all the age of the male persons in a list, and this method use a method that give only the male people. Smething like that:

```
public int getMaleAgeSum(List<People> paramPeople)
{
    List<People> lstMalePeople = getMalePeople(paramPeople);

    return lstMalePeople.Sum(x=>x.Age);
}


public List<Poeple> getMales(List<People> paramPeople)
{
    return paramPeople.Where(x=>x.Genre == "M");
}
```

In this case I have two methods because perhaps it's interesting to be able to get the male people from a list, and I use this code in the first method.

If I test the first method, I set my Arranges (my test cases) thinking in the return of the method, the age, not thinking to test if the getMales method give the correct people, because for that I implement tests for this method.

Also in this case I have the two methods in the same class, but for example if I use a mothod from another class that really has the same philosophy that getMale, in theory I could use property injection, but I think that is overkill.

For me integration tests are when you test the correct functionality when you use two piece of code to get a result. I can think that this is the case, two methods that works together for a same objetive. But in this case it could be see as didive the complex and have more funcitionalities because I have two methods.

So my doubt is, this is integration test and for unit test I need property injection or in this case is unit testing too although I use two pieces of code?

Thanks.

For me integration is more when two piece of code but from differents sections. For example, when I have a method that use entity framework to get the data from database and then I havea method to manipulate the information.

But

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would typically write a unit test against a single public method or property. I am only interested in the results of executing that one method. If internally it calls other methods, or if I need to set some properties to first test the method, it is still a unit test - I even name my test (methodname)_condition_expectation so my intent is clear.

Integration comes into play when you pass the results of another piece of code into the object bring tested, most commonly through injection.

An integration test might be a test to make sure a repository class uses an entity model to store values, a unit test would mock the entity model and check it has been used correctly.

In your example, I would write unit tests for both methods to prove they do what they want. Writing a test to make sure the result of one passed into the other is ten irrelevant. If you know the first returns men and the second returns another summarisation, you already know that passing the results into the next method will work - because you've unit tested it.

That's my definition anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: I just re read your question and see you are nesting the method, in this case both would be considered unit tests - although testing sum of age would give you test code coverage on your getmales method.